# why google Webmaster does not accept web.sitemap created by Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, google-search-console

I recently create web.sitemap for may site. I want to declare this file to Google Web Master.
but Google doesn't accept it and say

```
"Your Sitemap does not appear to be in a supported format. 
Please ensure it meets our Sitemap guidelines and resubmit."
```

does really Microsoft `web.sitemap` is not standard for Google?
Can anyone help me with this approach?

Comment: Try this link: http://www.consultsarath.com/contents/articles/KB000018-generate-google-sitemap-for-aspnet-website-using-vbnet.aspx

Comment: I found solution in your link @logixologist . Thank

Comment: ok I will post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: OK my friend I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on a search of the web for the best way to use .NET to work with Google Site Map: 
http://www.consultsarath.com/contents/articles/KB000018-generate-google-sitemap-for-aspnet-website-using-vbnet.aspx